# How do you hide the preview pane in Evernote Web?

Tags: evernote

In the evernote web application I was not able to find a way to hide the preview pane when in list mode, once the preview pane is there.

I have found old forum posts, where others were looking for the same and the result seems "feature not implemented".

So how do you hide the preview pane in Evernote Web when in list mode?

Or is it simply not possible? Or is there at least a keyboard shortcut?

I found a workaround which I will post as an answer, but is there a real solution? A keyboard shortcut would still be better.

Comment: This is a forum request with an answer from evernote "not implemented" but from 2012 https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/26770-request-ability-to-hide-preview-pane/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can go to the "view options"

Then switch from list to snippets and then back to list again. THe preview pane is gone now until you next activate it by cklicking on a list entry.

Not very nice but better than no way at all. Really helpful if you want to see the list and need the whole page.